# Is storing FTP credentials in git-ftp settings in repository insecure?

Tags: git, security, ftp, config, local

I recently started using [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) to make web deployment less tedious. It's [man page](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/develop/man/git-ftp.1.md) tells me to store the FTP credentials in the local git repository's config for ease of use. I'm just an ordinary guy with hardly any dangerous nemeses, so storing them locally on my computer in plaintext isn't much of a problem. Putting the FTP credentials in a public repository on Github for everyone to see, however, doesn't seem that smart.

To be clear, this is what I mean with "storing in plaintext":

```
git config git-ftp.password my_secret_password_in_local_git_repo_config
```

I am concerned that the (non-global) git configuration might get pushed to the remote repository (which is located on Github as a public repository).

So, my question is: **can this happen?**

Everything looks as though I have nothing to worry about (e.g. my directory is still clean after applying some settings), but I'm still a bit weary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my best knowledge these are local client side configuration settings and not shared between repositories.